# Chrome display PDF file in different language

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf

I use Chrome to open PDF file online, the PDF file is all Traditional Chinese.

However, Chrome display that file in Simplified Chinese.  But not all file, only few files got this issue.

My colleague no this issue.

I tried to reinstall & reset Chrome setting, delete AppData folder, delete all temp folder, reinstall Adobe Reader, all same result.

The file is store on company portal, 500 user is able to access, 5 user got this issue.

Other colleague login to this computer also got same issue.

Affected user login their account in other computers without issue.
Anyone got similar issue and any solution?

Comment: Have you talked to your system Administrator?

Comment: Yes, Ramhound, our IT use admin right to troubleshoot it, they have no idea why this happen

Comment: In general, special fonts in files mean you should embed the font so systems that don't have that font installed already will still be able to render the document. I don't recall how to do this, but the functionality is built in to Adobe Pro.

Comment: Have the Administrator wipe and restore the standard image. Any solution will require Administrative rights which you don’t have.

Comment: we have over 500 user here, we use same image to clone all device.

Comment: Appreciated if any expert can provide solution, 1 of the affected user is very high level in my office.  Our whole IT department got pressure.
Merry Christmas & Have a good weekend.